# Make a sticky div in a bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a way to make a div sticky to the bottom, like a footer, but inside a bootstrap grid, so not over the whole width.

[Bootstrap has an example of a sticky footer](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/), I tried to tweak it to make it work in my case but couldn't.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756997/how-to-create-a-sticky-footer-that-plays-well-with-bootstrap-3) is another approach, but also assumes your sticky div is not nested inside another div.

Below is my code, I need to make `.app-footer` sticky to the bottom over the width of it's parent div.

```
<div class="row main">
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-4 col-lg-5">...</div>

  <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
    <div class="app"></div>
    <div class="app-footer"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-4 col-lg-5">...</div>
</div>
```

Edit: the CSS I've tried but doesn't work:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
.app {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
  /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0 0 60px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
.app-footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Edit: Ok, got it. The solution seems to be to add {position: relative; height: 100%} to ALL parent divs. In my case I had the grid wrapped in `<div class="row">`, when I added it there too it worked.

Comment: You want it sticky to the bottom of the window or to the bottom of the parent element?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make the nested child div positioned to the bottom of the parent div:

add {position:relative} to the css of the the parent div;
add {position:absolute;bottom:0} to the css of the the child div;

the nested div should be the same width as the parent (taknig into account the padding and margins), but you could force it to be by adding width:100% to the child div's css

Answer (score -1):

You could try this in your CSS:

```
.app-footer{
  position: absoute;
  bottom: 0px
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this css to make your app-footer div sticky:

```
.app-footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
}
```