# Bootstrap responsive table within display:table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap responsive `table` which is within a `div` with the `CSS` `display:table`. This seems to be preventing the table from becoming responsive. How can I make the table responsive without changing the outer `CSS`?

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzr07183/)

For reference, `display:table` is used to create a "sticky footer": [How to create a sticky footer that plays well with Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756997/how-to-create-a-sticky-footer-that-plays-well-with-bootstrap-3)

Comment: is display:table is compulsory to have in code?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, its used by the sticky footer and is not something I can readily change

Comment: It is responsive But your items are to long so it doesn't show the rest of table

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the current css you have to make your text responsive to fix this problem.
set the `font size` and instead of `px` use `vm`, `vw`, `vh` or `vmin` These suffixes make your text responseive.
[image]

Comment: Setting `font-size: 1vmin` on the table works but it makes the text so small its unreadable which isn't really a great solution

Comment: Use `font-size: 2vw`

Comment: Using 2vw leads to the table being too big for the viewport and gets whole page horizontal scrolling

Answer (score 0):

try this, may be this will help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.content-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.table-responsive {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: -moz-stack;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="content-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Bookings</h3></div>
          <div class="bookings_list">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Customer</th>
                        <th>Provider</th>
                        <th>Agent</th>
                        <th>Service</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr class="clickable" action="push" href="/bookings/UY6001">
                        <td>123</td>
                        <td>John Smith</td>
                        <td>ACME Corp</td>
                        <td>Mike</td>
                        <td>123456</td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="clickable" action="push" href="/bookings/UY6000">
                        <td>123</td>
                        <td>John Smith</td>
                        <td>ACME Corp</td>
                        <td>Mike</td>
                        <td>123456</td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you cant see responsive table here, just copy my code and paste in notepad, then try

Answer (score 0):

Set your `container`'s width based on the viewport instead of a percentage value:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzr07183/1/)

Since `container` is a pretty common class in bootstrap, you might consider adding a custom class to the specific element you want to add this style to.

Comment: Interesting solution but I still seem to get a little bit of whole page horizontal scrolling using 100vw and anything less creates a slight margin